# "Unknown element o" when calling plot in EC2 instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, matplotlib, tensorflow, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance with everything needed installed and upgraded.

I keep getting a warning and an error when I try to create a plot.

The warning is:

```
MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Adding an axes using the same arguments as a previous axes currently reuses the earlier instance.  In a future version, a new instance will always be created and returned.  Meanwhile, this warning can be suppressed, and the future behavior ensured, by passing a unique label to each axes instance.
```

The error that comes immediately afterwards:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/ec2-user/mnn/nn_tp_thread.py", line 241, in run
    plt.plot(mean_prediction_last_10)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 3347, in plot
    ax = gca()
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 984, in gca
    return gcf().gca(**kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1817, in gca
    return self.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1240, in add_subplot
    self._axstack.add(key, a)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 142, in add
    Stack.remove(self, (key, a_existing))
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py", line 1254, in remove
    raise ValueError('Unknown element o')
ValueError: Unknown element o
```

My code is:

```
            thread_locker.acquire()

            mean_prediction_last_10 = mean_prediction[9:]
            mean_prediction_last_10
            plt.plot(mean_prediction_last_10)
            plt.title('Price Prediction - ' + str(datetime.datetime.now().time()))
            plt.xlabel('Time')
            plt.ylabel('Mean Price')
            plt.legend()
            # plt.show()
            fig = plt.figure()
            fig.savefig("/static/images/Last_prediction_"+ timeframe +".png")
            thread_locker.release()
```

I have searched and tried many things but with no success. Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**
Changing my code to clear any figures and plots (although there shouldn't exist any):

```
            thread_locker.acquire()
            plt.clf()
            plt.close()
            mean_prediction_last_10 = mean_prediction[9:]
            plt.plot(mean_prediction_last_10)
            fig = plt.figure()
            plt.title('Price Prediction - ' + str(datetime.datetime.now().time()))
            plt.xlabel('Time')
            plt.ylabel('Mean Price')
            plt.legend()
            # plt.show()

            fig.savefig("/static/images/Last_prediction_"+ timeframe +".png")
            thread_locker.release()
```

I get a message like:

```
No handles with labels found to put in legend.
```

and a different error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/ec2-user/mnn/nn_tp_thread.py", line 237, in run
    plt.clf()
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 686, in clf
    gcf().clf()
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1413, in clf
    self.delaxes(ax)         # removes ax from self._axstack
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1007, in delaxes
    self._axstack.remove(ax)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 113, in remove
    Stack.remove(self, self._entry_from_axes(a))
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 108, in _entry_from_axes
    ind, k = {a: (ind, k) for k, (ind, a) in self._elements}[e]
KeyError: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f165b4e10b8>
```

Comment: What the error means is that the attempt to remove an element from a `Stack` fails, because that element hasn't been part of the `Stack` in the first place. Without a [mcve], i.e. a runnable example, this is probably all one can say at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I have updated my question with the newest developments if you have a moment to take a look.

Comment: Would you mind providing a [mcve], i.e. a code that one can copy, paste and run?

Comment: I will look into it, but it is somewhat complicated because at the same thread I'm using tensorflow to load and train a model and issue predictions with it.
This part of thread code. The interesting thing is that when I limit the number of threads or don't use model.fit(), the error seems to go away.

Comment: ...meaning that in general the code above works fine, right? I think from that you see for yourself that it is really hard to find the cause of the issue without an example case.

Answer (score 3):

I also had an error "Unknown element o" when I was trying to obtain spectrogram data with matplotlib:

```
pxx, freqs, bins, im = plt.specgram(sample,  NFFT=256, Fs=10000, noverlap=120)
```

I was using this line during training model, so I didn't need plotting and I solved it by closing the window and removing axis:

```
pxx, freqs, bins, im = plt.specgram(sample,  NFFT=256, Fs=10000, noverlap=120)
plt.axis('off')
plt.close()
```

I hope someone find this helpful.